# Querying rails model based on two fields of which one is sometimes null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.1

In my model `User`, there already exists an `id` column which is auto-incremented. Now I plan to have a unique name for the user.

Now, the user won't be asked for it in the sign up process, so by default, I would like the column to *return* `"user" + id` when called like

```
user.profile_name #=> should return "user#{user.id}" if nil
```

I don't want to duplicate the data, so I would want to keep the field `nil` until the user enters one.

So, I thought of creating a custom function(or overriding the `profile_name` if possible)

```
# model User.rb
def get_identifier
   profile_name ? profile_name : "user#{id}"
end
```

And using `where` to find the user

```
id, user = params[:identifier], nil
if id[0..3] == "user"
   user = User.find_by_id(id[3..-1].to_num)
else
   user = User.find_by profile_name: id
```

But this seems not to be a rails way. I would have to take care of both the cases even when querying.

Is there any way to simplify this in Rails that I'm missing? Else can the current approach be bettered (apart from refactoring the code into methods)?

P.S The question is tagged appropriately with the versions I'm using. Ruby version - 2.1.5

Comment: If someone can phrase the title better, please edit freely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to preface with this answer with my opinion that your hesitation to "duplicate the data", where the data is really just the id, might be uncalled for. It's not user-editable or anything, so I'm not sure what the downsides are if you're not counting bytes in your database size.

Given the constraints of the question, I'd look at an implementation like this:

```
class User
  def self.find_by_profile_name(profile_name)
    where(profile_name: profile_name).first || find_by_default_profile_name(profile_name)
  end

  def self.find_by_default_profile_name(profile_name)
    where(id: DefaultProfileName.from_profile_name(profile_name).id)
  end
end


class DefaultProfileName
  attr_accessor :id

  def self.from_profile_name(profile_name)
    new(profile_name.sub('user', ''))  
  end

  def initialize(id)
    self.id = id
  end

  def to_s
    "user#{id}"
  end
end
```

I'm sure this could be improved on, but the main takeaway is that encapsulating your default profile name functionality in its own class enables making this bit of functionality contained and more manageable.

Comment: I like this solution..by duplicating the data, I meant that it's wastage of resources to save like this: `id: 1, profile_name: user1` in the table, when we can just frame it in the code. Also by *I'm sure this could be improved on* what are you meaning? How can this be still improved?

Comment: Regarding data duplication: I just don't think that your servers will be terribly upset if you start serving one extra string per record. Regarding possible improvements: that was just a disclaimer that the code I provided probably isn't the absolute ultimate given your business requirements, but I do believe it's a good place to start.

Comment: Okay..I'm not well-versed in DB, so I'd take your word for it.. but how would I save the id, since the id will be only available after saving the record? Should I get the id after saving and again update the `profile_name` and then again store it?

Comment: I know of two approaches to solving that: use a callback  (after_create) or wrap user creation in a service class that saves the user and then explicitly sets the default profile name if one wasn't provided after the user was created. I'd recommend the latter. Callbacks tend to cause issues down the line and can make testing more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that you need to backfill `profile_name`s for existing users. Otherwise you might run into all kinds of interesting problems.

For example: There are the existing users `1` and `2`, both do not have a unique username yet. User `1` has the `profile_name` `user1`, analog for user `2` which has `user2` as the `profile_name` `user2`. Now user `1` decides to set a `profile_name` and he sets its `profile_name` to `user2`, what is a unique `profile_name` at the moment - at least from a Rails validator's point of view.

To avoid this problems: Always set a unique `profile_name` and backfill `profile_name`s for existing users.

Comment: I thought of that, and just didn't specify that I'd add like via code `"_user#{user.id}"`  and users can't start their profile name with `_` in the UI.